# How do I add space between thumbnails without the last thumbnail going to the next line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails, spacing

I have a basic thumbnail display using bootstrap. I want to have 3 images in a row and go down to 2 images when making the page smaller. I had this worked out until I added a margin-right to add some space in between thumbnails. Once I did this it pushed that third image down to the next line. I tried playing around with the padding and margin and I just cant get that third thumbnail to stay on the same line. I also tried changing it to col-sm-3 and that did not seem to work either.

HTML:

```
<div class="work">
<ul>
<li class="thumbnail col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a href="#honey" data-toggle="modal"><img src="thumbnails.png"/></a></li>
<li class="thumbnail col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a href="#honey" data-toggle="modal"><img src="thumbnails.png"/></a></li>
<li class="thumbnail col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a href="#honey" data-toggle="modal"><img src="thumbnails.png"/></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.work {
padding: 0px 40px 0px 0px;
max-width: 100%;
}

.thumbnail {
margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: have you tried decreasing the padding? its really hard to say without knowing how wide `.work` is (is it the entire page width, or confined by a container?) as well as how wide the images are

Comment: yes, I tried it with no padding and that didn't fix it

Comment: You can't add margin to it without it dropping to the next line. Bootstrap is set up so that the columns take up exactly 100% width of the container. You're using three 4-column elements which takes up 100% width, adding any margin to those divs is going to make it extend beyond 100%.

Comment: You can increase or decrease the gap between thumbnails.

Comment: instead of setting margin for the `li` elements, use padding on them so that the `a` tags would be viewed separately as you want them to. Note that messing around with bootstrap grid's basic structure would make problems in the behavior

Comment: Yes, that was my second option adding padding to the thumbnail itself. But I really wanted space between the thumbnails, as it looks nicer. Is there any way to achieve this with bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% if this what you mean, but here it goes:

**HTML**

```
<div class="work">
    <ul>
        <li class="thumbnail col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a href="#honey" data-toggle="modal"><img src="thumbnails.png"/></a></li>
        <li class="thumbnail col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a href="#honey" data-toggle="modal"><img src="thumbnails.png"/></a></li>
        <li class="thumbnail col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a href="#honey" data-toggle="modal"><img src="thumbnails.png"/></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.thumbnail {
    border:0;
}
.thumbnail a{
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    background:red;
}
.thumbnail img{
    width:100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ax7wcLo4/2

Comment: Why using `display: inline-block` when the `col-` classes already set them float to left alongside each other?

Comment: @FarzadYZ True that. Thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to separate the `li` elements, you should do that without bootstrap's default grid system.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
```

Use class `.list-inline` on th e`ul` element and set the below css for them;

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%
}
li {
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

**Be Aware**: `calc` has some compatibility issues based on your browser support range.
[Can I Use Link for CALC](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `thumbnail` inside of a `column`, not combined. If you need this inside a list it can be change to that as well > See [Default Bootstrap Example](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails-default).

See working Snippet at Full Page.

```css
body,
html {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.row.no-list-style {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -55px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h3>Default</h3>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="#honey">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/f00" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="#honey">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/000" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="#honey">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/f00" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Inside a List</h3>

  <ul class="row no-list-style">
    <li class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="#honey">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/ff0" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="#honey">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/000" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="#honey">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/ff0" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```